# Action of $\pi_1(B)$ on Higher Homotopy groups $\pi_n(F)$ for a Fibration $F \to E \to B$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fibration

Let $F \to E \to B$ be a *principal fibration*, ie obtainable as a pullback from a path loop fibration $PX \to X$. Any path $\gamma: b_0 \to b_1$  in $B$ lifts to a homotopy equivalence $\overline{\gamma}:F(b_0) \simeq
F(b_1)$ (by fibre transport). In particular, a loop in $B$ gives a
self homotopy equivalence of $F$.

In [these Notes](https://www.ms.uky.edu/%7Eguillou/S11/527-Week11.pdf) is also stated that if $F$ is simply connected ($\pi_1(F)=0$), this gives a well-defined action of $\pi_1(B)$
on $\pi_n(F)$ for all $n$.

Why well definedness of this action depends on simply connectedness of $F$? Isn't this action simply given by $[\gamma] \cdot [f] = [\overline{\gamma} \cdot f]$ where $f: S^n \to F$ represents $[f] \in \pi_n(F)$ and $\overline{\gamma}: F \to F$ a lift of loop $\gamma: S^1 \to B$. Where this action would be not well defined if $F$ would be not simply connected?

Comment: This is just a guess. The induced map $\overline{\gamma}$ doesn't necessarily send a basepoint to a basepoint.  So to actually get an action in $\pi_k(F,x)$ we need an isomorphism from $\pi_k(F,\overline{\gamma}(x))$ to $\pi_k(F,x)$.  Such an isomorphism is given by choosing a path in $F$ from $x$ to $\overline{\gamma}(x)$.  But different choices of path can give different isomorphisms.  However, if $F$ is simply connected, then all paths induce the same isomorphism.